# fortran pointer to vector subscript

Tags: pointers, fortran

I'm trying to do something similar:

```
integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: abfi   
real, dimension(5),target :: testt
real, pointer :: testp(:)
testt=(/2,.1,.2,1,1/)
.
.
allocate( abfi( count(testt.ge..5) ) )
abfi=pack([(ix,ix=1,size(testt))],testt.ge..5)      
testp => testt(abfi)
```

So, I'd like to point directly at a masked subarray, but it seems impossible.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Yes, I have an array continuously varying, in which I have to check which elements assume values under a  certain threshold, in order to perform other operations on such portion of the original array. I'm not an expert in Fortan, but I have seen that, in general, pointers arrays are very efficient in terms of computational time; so, I was wondering if it is possible to directly use a pointer subarray to the "masked" original array.